# Add values of items within two IEnumerable collections

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I have two IEnumerable collections of generic objects. Each object has a name and value property. The name is a string and the value is a double.

I would like to merge the two into one and add the value properties. For example, say an object that is present in both collection with the following properties:

```
Collection 1:                Collection 2:
  Name: Var1                   Name: Var1  
  Value: 2.67                  Value: 4.32
```

In the final collection I'd like to merge the above two as:

```
Result Collection:
  Name: Var1
  Value: 6.99
```

I know the hard/long way of doing it using a foreach loop, by iterating over each one which is being very expensive since my collection has about 150,000 objects each. However, I'm trying to figure out if there is an easier and faster way of doing this using Linq?

Update in response to  Yuval Itzchakov's comment:

The long/hard way that I've tried is:

```
foreach(var item in collection1)
{
   if(collection2.where(x => x.Name == item.Name).Count() == 1)
   {
      item.value += collection2.First(x => x.Name == item.Name).value;
   }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that implementing the same functionality with Linq will be inexpensive?  LINQ will also iterate through your objects. Being invisible in your code doesn't mean that iteration will not be made.

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou Probably wishful thinking? And kind of hoping the great minds at Microsoft devised a better algorithm than the one I've currently conceived of?

Comment: Is it a known type object or you just know that there are listed fields?

Comment: Also is there a chance that there are same keys in one collection?

Comment: Well they might  for a General case. But i think any implementation targeting general cases will always be slower from an implementation which targets your specific case.

Comment: @VadimMartynov It's an object of a custom struct. If by keys you mean the name, then no. The names are unique in both collections.

Comment: Can you guarantee a) that each key is in both lists, and b) that each key is in each list only once? If not, what behavior do you expect?

Comment: @JeevanJose What are your inputs? Do collection 1 & 2 both contain the same types, or different types that happen to have the same property names? Are these anonymous types? Also, what is your required output: do you want to modify one of the original collections (code in your question would seem to imply this), or return an entirely new collection type (and if so, what type of collection)?

Comment: @IainGalloway Yes, the 'Name' field will only appear once in a collection. No, the same key may not be present in both. In the latter case, I'd still be retrieving the value field but not adding anything to it.

Comment: @StevenRands They both contain the same types. It doesn't really matter if  one of the collections is modified. Ideally the result collection would be a third collection. Whichever is faster basically.

Comment: @JeevanJose Okay, then Vadim's answer is pretty much what I would have suggested if you want a pure LINQ solution.

Comment: @StevenRands Yes, that answer looks pretty good. I'm not after a pure linq solution per se. Just whatever is the fastest. I'm optimizing for CPU not memory at this point.

Comment: @JeevanJose If your collections have each key once, I suggest you to check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34440227/815590

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most generic solution that includes cases with duplicated keys can be implemented with [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) LINQ methods:

```
var result = firstCollection
    .Concat(secondCollection)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => new Foo { Name = g.Key, Value = g.Sum(f => f.Value) });
    // Foo is an example of your element class. You can use anonymous classes
    //.Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Value = g.Sum(f => f.Value) });
```

Algorithmic complexity of this solution is O(n).

If you want to have maximum performance you can using ordinal string comparation:

```
var result = firstCollection
    .Concat(secondCollection)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name, x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal)
    .Select(g => new Foo { Name = g.Key, Value = g.Sum(f => f.Value) });
```

Comment: O(n) is probably the best so far. I'll wait to see what if someone else comes with a better one before accepting this. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @JeevanJose this takes my machine 0.0008366s for 150000 elements in each list. My answer uses 0.0005903s for the same lists. So if you have only 150000 records, there is absolutly no performance issue here and you may use this better looking code from Vadim.

Comment: @RenéVogt I've accepted his answer. Thank you as well for answering.

Comment: Better then O(n) algorithm? :) OK, I'm glad that my decision is suitable for you.
Yes, there is one better solution. Use `.GroupBy(x => x.Name, x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal)` to compare string in the fastest way.

Comment: You won't be able to get something better than O(n), since you have to look at every item in both collections at least once.

Comment: Haha. Yes, I don't know why I was looking for O(n log n).

Comment: Actaually O(n) means O(C*n) where C is the constant value that is not dependent on collection size. There is a "long" way to implement faster algorithm with the same complexity.

Answer (score 3):

To make things faster you can turn the first list into a dictionary. So you iterate over that only once. Then you can iterate over the second and update the values in your dictionary, which is quite fast.

I'm not sure if you meant *"collections of generic types"* or *"collections of anonymous types"*. Anonymous types would need some changes in my solution:

```
    public class Poco
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double D { get; set; }
    }
    private static IEnumerable<Poco> Merge(IEnumerable<Poco> list1, IEnumerable<Poco> list2)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Poco> dict1 = list1.ToDictionary(l => l.Name, l => l);
        foreach (Poco p in list2)
        {
            if (dict1.ContainsKey(p.Name))
            {
                Poco result = dict1[p.Name];
                result.D += p.D;
                yield return result;
                continue;
            }

            yield return p;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** in this code I change the original data in the source collections. So maybe you will need to create new instances of `Poco` to avoid that. And it will only work if the `Name`s are unique per collection.

**Edit:** the handling of multiple occurences of `Name` in the second collection is a little different than your code snippet you added after my answer. But I think you can do the changes. The main point for performance in this code is using the dictionary.

**Edit:** missed the `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have duplicated key in same list, there is a left join
But the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/34439894/815590 is a lot better.

```
public class Poco
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

var listA = new List<Poco> { new Poco { Name = "Var1", Value = 2.67 } };
var listB = new List<Poco> { new Poco { Name = "Var1", Value = 4.32 } };

var merged = (from a in listA
              join b in listB on a.Name equals b.Name into tempGroup
              from a2 in tempGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select a2 == null ? a : new Poco { Name = a.Name, Value = a.Value + a2.Value });
```

Comment: Isn't this much more expensive than Vadim's answer? There would be some CPU cycles involved in converting each to list first?

Comment: @JeevanJose I added the list, just to show some data, you can user your IEnumerable collections. Both list is just for didactic purpose.

Comment: @JeevanJose btw the Vadim's answer is a lot better in performance.